# LUA Script, Anyone can help? Conditional

Tags: string, lua, null, conditional-statements

```
function recoil_mode()
    if IsKeyLockOn(mode_switch_key) then
        if mode_switch then
            if IsKeyLockOn(full_mode_key) and full_mode then
                return "fullof4x"
            else
                return "quadruple"
            end
        end
    end
    if not IsKeyLockOn(mode_switch_key) then
        if not mode_switch then
            if IsKeyLockOn(full_mode_key) and full_mode then
                return "full"
            else
                return "basic"
            end
        end
    end
end
```

This is a code, a conditional that is supposed to check for a key press. 
My biggest problem is the "mode_switch" part, which is a bool , local 
If mode_switch = True then that means that the user is able to switch modes.

Now, when I run this code through this other function.

```
function recoil_value(_weapon,_duration)
    local _mode = recoil_mode()
    local step = (math.floor(_duration/recoil_table[_weapon]["speed"])) + 1
    if step > #recoil_table[_weapon][_mode] then
        step = #recoil_table[_weapon][_mode]
    end
```

I get an error;
[string "LuaVM"]:560: attempt to get length of field '?' (a nil value)

Anyone knows what is going on?

Comment: We don't really have enough information to help you at the moment. If I had to guess, I'd say that `recoil_mode()` is returning `nil`. 

Is it possible for `IsKeyLockOn(mode_switch_key)` to be `true` and `mode_switch` be `false` or vice-versa?

Comment: As I can see, `KeyLockOn` has 2 states and `mode_switch` has 2 states, resulting in 4 possible states to handle. You basically only handle two. Do you have a guarantee that other two are not happening (for example KeyLockOn and not mode_switch, so that the function returns nil value. 

In short, I think you need to redesign `function recoil_mode()`

Comment: The error message says that `recoil_table[_weapon][_mode]` is `nil`, but `nil` does not have length

Comment: @DavisDude Yes that is possible, but if the user presses the key lock is on for like "Num lock" for example, and mode_switch key is off then it will execute the else statement

Comment: @macroland Ok, I'll definitely try doing that.

Comment: @ANewbieCoder print the value of `_mode`